# How to use Python in .NET-Core application?

Tags: python, asp.net-core, ironpython, .net-core

How to use Python in .NET-Core application? I need this for the purposes of Hackathon so the solution don't have to be 'elegant'. I've read that it's impassible to run Python scripts directly because there exists only library IronPython for standard ASP.NET but no for .NET-Core. 
So what is the simplest way to use Python scripts?
(Because it's hackathon it's ok to use even PHP server or selenium etc. only to execute script)

Comment: Just FYI about IronPython for .net core: IronPython is not yet available for .net core. It's still in development and comes with .net core 1.1 or 1.2 see https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/issues/77

Comment: Ok, but there have to be same not too complicated way to go around. I've never seen in my live Python scripts, but i guess it is possible to find/make website on which i can put my script, post parameters, by JSON from my ASP app and gets result. It is possible?

Comment: you could go the way over Python and make a python web-api (django,...) and call the web-api from c#. But I don't think, it's possible (at least for now) to combine python with net core. net core is still veeeery young. Or you go the way, writing python scripts and call them with `Process` and call python.exe with the script-path. I don't know any other way...

Comment: IronPython 2 is available for Python2 inside .NET Core however Python3 is not support yet and the project for supporting it has a giant title of DO NOT USE.

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```cs
public class RunCmd
{
    public string Run(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "python";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
        start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
        start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
 var res = new RunCmd().Run("your_python_file.py","params");
 Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: This does not work for `.Net Core 3.1` + `Python 3.8`. use a **batch script** file(`.bat`) for Windows or **shell script** file (`.sh`) for Linux to replace the `cmd.exe` or `bash`. You may add `C:\YOUR_PYTHON_PATH\python.exe %*` in `.bat` or add `/usr/bin/python3 "$@"` in `.sh`

Answer (score 21):

Since this shows up as one of the first entries in Google, one should probably also mention that IronPython fully supports .NetCore now, and it can easily be installed using NuGet.

This approach is simpler, since it's fewer lines of code and one less runtime to install and manage.  Plus, there are a number of benefits to keeping the execution in-process (performance, debugging, type safety, etc.).

1. Using NuGet, add the latest "IronPython" and "IronPython.StdLib".  **Alternatively**, add the following to the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IronPython" Version="2.7.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="IronPython.StdLib" Version="2.7.10" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
```

2. Create a function or class to make running scripts a bit more convenient:

```
public class PythonScript
{
    private ScriptEngine _engine;

    public PythonScript()
    {
        _engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    }

    public TResult RunFromString<TResult>(string code, string variableName)
    {
        // for easier debugging write it out to a file and call: _engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filePath);
        ScriptSource source = _engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
        CompiledCode cc = source.Compile();

        ScriptScope scope = _engine.CreateScope();
        cc.Execute(scope);

        return scope.GetVariable<TResult>(variableName);
    }
}
```

3. Run your scripts:

```
var py = new PythonScript();
var result = py.RunFromString<int>("d = 8", "d");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```